# Converting a 3D position to a 2D screen position

Tags: math, 3d, 2d, converters

I am trying to create a screen overlay for an existing computer game. This overlay should display icons that show certain locations in the 3D world. Now because I do not have access to the data I want to be able to get the screen positions, I have to figure it out using the following variables:

- Player position (x,y,z)
- Camera position (x,y,z)
- Point position (x,y,z)
- Camera Angle(FOV)

Using these variables I managed to get the right and left edge of the camera view. Using these 2 variables I am able to get the point between 0 and 1 where the icon should be displayed on the x axis. (0 is on the left edge, 1 is right edge) This seems to work quite well, but only if I am aligned to either the X or Z axis, as shown in the following example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew2pn.png

The problem is, I have no clue on how to make this work when the camera rotates. I've tried combining the 2 points that work alone, but also with other variables like the camera-player world rotation and angles.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might be able to make this work? If I forgot to supply any info please let me know!

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pretty good articles on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection), and other tutorials online (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2158/A-short-discussion-on-mapping-3D-objects-to-a-2D-d).

Essentially, for this simple instance, it boils down to rotating everything in a virtual space before rendering. The points you want to draw are moved in relation to the camera position, so that the camera becomes the new axis point, and then you can draw as before.

### A simple top down ascii-art example:

( `[]<` is the camera, `a`, `b`, and `c` are points)

**What you can already draw:**

```
^    <-----y------>
| 
|            b
|    []<        a
x
|          c
|
|
v
```

**What you can't draw:** *(the camera moved and rotated)*

```
     <-----y------>

^         [ ]
|          ^
|            b
x               a
|       c
|
v
```

So you need to map (usually using matrixies) the camera's global position against the positions of everything else, so that you end up with:

**After transformation:**

```
            <---------fake y------>

      ^          
      |         a
      |       
 fake |       b 
   x: |   []<
      |             c
      |
      v
```

Which you can now draw as normal.  I'm not an expert on this, but does this help to get you started?

Comment: Yes! This definitely does. I don't know why I haven't thought of it though. Thanks for the help :)